# first character could be string second character should be numeric and rest should be alphanumeric

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have string which first contain either numeric or alphabet or hyphen. if first character is numeric so second character should be character and rest should be any occurrence of numeric, alphabet and hyphen.

I tried with :

```
([A-Za-z-]{1})(?![A-Za-z-]{1})([A-Za-z-]{61})
```

String is valid:

1. if only alphabet in string and one character in string.
2. if only hyphen in string and one character in string.
3. if first character is numeric then second character should be alphabet or hyphen and rest could be alphabet, numeric or hyphen.
4. No special character or tab or space only hyphen is allowed.
5. Max length of string is 63 characters.

for example:

```
1 : invalid
11 : invalid 
;1 : invalid
1; : invalid
a; : invalid
;a : invalid
- : valid
a : valid
aa : valid
a1 : valid
1a : valid
1- : valid
-1 : valid
a- : valid
-a : valid

11testisgoingon : invalid 
;1testingisgoingon : invalid
1;testingisgoingon : invalid
a;testingisgoingon : invalid
;atestingisgoingon : invalid
-testingisgoingon : valid
atestingisgoingon : valid
aatestingisgoingon : valid
a1testingisgoingon : valid
1atestingisgoingon : valid
1-testingisgoingon : valid
-1testingisgoingon : valid
a-testingisgoingon : valid
-atestingisgoingon : valid

([A-Za-z-])(?![A-Za-z-])
```

But this work well for first two characters. But if more than two characters are there then it's incorrect.

Comment: This smells like homework.  Have you tried a regex yet?

Comment: yes i started with: ([A-Za-z-])(?![A-Za-z-]). This works well upto 2 character that means half condition fulfilled. If I have string with more than 2 character it doesn't give desired result. My only query is how to extend this regex

Comment: Based on your provided data, maybe this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/2nYe49/1) `^(?=.{0,63}$)(?:[a-zA-Za-z-][A-Za-z\d-]?|\d[A-Za-z-])[A-Za-z‌​-]*$` can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^(([0-9][a-z-][a-z0-9-]{0,60})?(-?[a-z0-9])?([a-z0-9]-?)?([a-z-][a-z0-9-]{0,62})?){1}$
```

with flags "Multiline, IgnoreCase" for

```
11testisgoingoninvalid 
;1testingisgoingonnvalid
1;testingisgoingoninvalid
a;testingisgoingoninvalid
;atestingisgoingoninvalid
-testingisgoingonvalid
atestingisgoingonvalid
aatestingisgoingonvalid
a1testingisgoingonvalid
1atestingisgoingonvalid
1-testingisgoingonvalid
-1testingisgoingonvalid
a-testingisgoingonvalid
-atestingisgoingon
```

in https://regexr.com/.

Explanation:

Add IgnoreCase flag to regex or add `A-Z` to any `[a-z]`

```
^((...)?(...)?(...)?(...)?){1}$
    ->  We set up an outer capturing group containing 
        4 inner ones wich may or may no occure. In total 
        only 1 must match.  
        The capturing group must fill the whole line, and
        the inner caputring groups model your requirements:

    ([0-9][a-z-][a-z0-9-]{0,60})?    
         -> STARTS with numeric, 
             followed by alphabetic or hyphen, 
             followed by anything 
             up to 63 characters in total   

    (-?[a-z0-9])?   
    ([a-z0-9]-?)?
        -> one character prefixed/followed by hyphen

    ([a-z-][a-z0-9-]{0,62})?
        -> generic long text not started by numeric
            followed by anything
            up to 63 characters long
```